# Update Rabbitmq exchange type when using spring integration

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-integration

I currently have a defined rabbitmq exchange in my spring xml that is a fanout. I want to change it to a direct but when i deploy my new project the exchange is not updated. I see spring tries to create but fails.

Is there an override I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cannot be done; you can't change an exchange type after it is created.

You have to delete it and recreate.

Comment: So I have my project running as a service so it auto-recreates. I have to disable the service, delete the exchange/queue, and then put the new xml in and then start the service.

Sad that this is the only way.

Comment: It's a limitation of the broker; so why not create it with the right type in the first place?